# Limit video streaming with lighttpd & Mod_h264 for x minutes

Tags: lighttpd, video-streaming

I'm running video streaming with lighttpd & mod_h264 on CentOS.
Now, I want to set to client can only watch the movie for the first x minutes. Example: 10 minutes.
Who can give me a solution for this?
Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `start` and `end` parameters as part of the url

```
http://www.example.com/video.mp4?start=15&end=600
```

Which should start the video at 0 and let it run for 10 minutes.

It may be better to use a preview link and some server side rewriting though as the above could easily be adjusted manually.

Enable url rewriting by having `"mod_rewrite"` as part of the `server.modules`.

Add this

```
url.rewrite = (
"(.*)/preview$" => "$1?start=0&end=600"
)
```

which, given a url like

```
 http://www.example.com/video.mp4/preview
```

will provide the first 10 minutes of the file.

Comment: Thanks to @lain, But How to hidden this "start=0&end=600" or /preview or generate new link for prevent hotlink?

Comment: @longser: I already answered that - Make your preview URL end in `/preview` and then use the url.rewrite rule I provided.

Comment: @lain I think what he is asking is how can you prevent someone from hitting the url /video.mp4?start=15&end=600 directly.  I don't see where the solution outlined would do this, but maybe I am missing something.